# Gnus: show original article when replying

Tags: window, gnus

When I hit `r` (or `f/F/R`) in a gnus summary, I get a fullscreen view of the unsent Message. Is there some builtin way to put the new Message buffer in the window that had the Summary buffer, so I can look at the Article while replying?